# Designing Own Library in CodeIgniter or PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm a newbie implementing OOP in PHP. For PHP project, I often use codeigniter framework. Currently, I face a problem in designing classes for my own library.
Here is the description:

```
class ABC{
        function A(){

        }
        function B(){

        }
        function C(){

        }
}
class XYZ{
        function A(){

        }
        function similarToB(){

        }
        function X(){

        }
}
```

Class ABC and XYZ have similar features. Function **A** is shared between both classes. **Function B** from class ABC is similar to **function similarToB** from class XYZ (they have the same name and parameter, but different implementation). **Function C** is totally different from **function X**. There may be also another similar classes.
What is the best way to design those classes (e.g. using inheritance, interface, etc)?

Comment: Too abstract; the correct answer depends on what you're actually modelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Recommendation:

```
class ancestor { 
    public function A() { }
}

interface BInterface { 
    public function B();
}

class ABC extends ancestor implements BInterface {
    public function B() { }
    public function C() { }
}

class XYZ extends ancestor implements BInterface {
    public function B() { }
    public function X() { }
}
```

I know everyone is going to give you the "it depends" shtick (and it really does depend on what you want to do), but I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for providing me an option. I think this could work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could code this up as a single class, keep it as two classes or even code it up as eight separate classes. Perhaps you could could up one base class then have two classes which extend the base class.

Which is best depends on what you are trying to do.

Essentially most programing is is really building an abstract model of some real world process which itself may be real or abstract. The best design is the one which most closely reflects the real world process.

So if you were trying to implement say a "mail order" and a "direct sale" which are both variations on a sale, I would recommend a base "sales" class with classes "mail_order" and "direct_order" which extend the base class.

Conversely if you were trying to implement a "mail order" and a "mail advertising" which are separate businees processes that just happen to use the postal system I would keep the classes completely separate.